# limit of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find the limit of this question 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \left( \frac{\sin x}{\sin a} \right)^{\frac{1}{x-a}}$$ where $a \neq k\pi$ with k an integer.

We can write this as : $$\exp\left({\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\dfrac{1}{x-a}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin a} \right)} \right)$$

How to proceed further?

Comment: You missed the logarithm...

Comment: @Eric What was the need to delete the comments?

Comment: @user17762: I hope you received my last comment in your inbox - to answer your question, mostly the general principle that it is better to discuss things in chat (there are still logs of all the chats that take place) rather on the questions themselves.  Also, in some sense the comments were 'obsolete'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to a}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin a}\right)^{\dfrac1{x-a}}$$

$$=e^{\lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{\ln \frac{\sin x}{\sin a}}{x-a}\right)}$$

Now, $\lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{\ln \frac{\sin x}{\sin a}}{x-a}\right)=\lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{\ln \sin x -\ln\sin a}{x-a}\right)$ which is of the form $\frac00$

So, applying L'Hospital Rule, $\lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{\ln \sin x -\ln\sin a}{x-a}\right)=\lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}1\right)=\cot a$

---

$$\lim_{x\to a}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin a}\right)^{\dfrac1{x-a}}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to a}\left(\left(1+\dfrac{\sin x-\sin a}{\sin a}\right)^{\dfrac{\sin a}{\sin x-\sin a}}\right)^{\dfrac{\sin x-\sin a}{(x-a)\sin a}}$$

$$=\left(\lim_{y\to0}\left(1+y\right)^{\dfrac1y}\right)^{\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{\sin x-\sin a}{(x-a)\sin a}} \text{( Putting }\dfrac{\sin x-\sin a}{\sin a}=y,\text{  as }x\to a,y\to 0 \text{)}$$

Now , $\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{\sin x-\sin a}{(x-a)}=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{\cos x}1$ (applying L'Hospital Rule)

$\implies \lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{\sin x-\sin a}{(x-a)}=\cos a$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to a}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin a}\right)^{\dfrac1{x-a}}=e^{\dfrac{\cos a}{\sin a}}=e^{\cot a}$$

Comment: Without using  L'Hospital Rule, $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\sin x-\sin a}{(x-a)}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin(z+a)-\sin a}z
=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z\cos a+(\cos z-1)\sin a}z$$ 
$$=\cos a\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z}z+\sin a\lim_{z\to0}\frac{(\cos z-1)}z
=\cos a-\frac{\sin a}2(\lim_{z\to0}z)\left(\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin \frac z2}{\frac z2}\right)^2=\cos a$$

Comment: @sultan, please find the alternative answer at the top.

Answer (score 1):

If it is allowed, you can also use Taylor series around $a$:

$$\sin x = \sin a + (x - a) \sin' a + O((x - a)^2) = \sin a + (x - a) \cos a + O((x - a)^2).$$

Plugging this in, we get

$$\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sin a}\right)^{\frac{1}{x-a}} = \left(\frac{\sin a + (x - a) \cos a + O((x - a)^2)}{\sin a}\right)^{\frac{1}{x-a}} = \left(1 + (x - a) \cot a + O((x - a)^2)\right)^{\frac{1}{x-a}} = \left[\left(1 + (x - a) \cot a + O((x - a)^2)\right)^{\frac{1}{(x-a) \cot a}}\right]^{\cot a} \quad \stackrel{(x \to a)}{\longrightarrow} \quad e^{\cot a}.$$